# SYMFONY2 - CSRF Token invalid Allwais

Tags: symfony, csrf-protection

So... basically it. i have a form class and then I render but allways return csrf error.

Form class:

```
class FormTest extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
           ->add(
                'urlTo',
                'url'
           )
        ->add('submit', 'submit');
    }

public function getName()
{
    return '';
}
```

}

In the controller:

```
...
$form = $this->createForm(new FormTest ());

$form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isSubmitted()) {
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            echo 1; die;
        }
    }
```

When I see in "isSubmited" and try "getData" I just get the url field, the token not, I don't know if it right.

View:

```
 {{ form_start(form) }}

                {{ form_widget(
                form.linkTo,
                {
                    'attr' : {
                    'class' : 'form-control col-xs-12',
                    'placeholder' : 'url here'
                }
                }
                ) }}

                {{ form_errors(form) }}

                {{ form_widget(
                form.submit,
                {
                    'label' : ' START',
                    'attr' : {
                    'class' : 'btn glyphicon glyphicon-send'
                }
                }
                ) }}

                {{ form_end(form) }}
```

And that's it, ALLWAYS return csrf token is invalid.

Ok, the problem is that the token is not storage in session... but i don't know why

Comment: Try add  `<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token }}" />` to the twig template

Comment: possible duplicate of [Symfony 2 Add CSRF Token when using a form without a class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136188/symfony-2-add-csrf-token-when-using-a-form-without-a-class)

Comment: it's not the same question. it's a session issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `form_rest(form)` which renders the remaining fields including token or you need to use `form_row(form._token)` to render the token manually.

`form_end(form)` is basically just `</form>`

Comment: You have a form with ```urlTo``` and a template with ```form.linkToDownload```. That doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: ah yes, but it's the same field, I change for it but I forgot change all he code, sorry