# CSRF token missing

Tags: symfony, twig

That's something driving me crazy.

Take these snippets of code

```
class CommonController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create delete form
     *
     * @param int $id
     *
     * @return Form
     */
    protected function createDeleteForm($id)
    {
        return $this->createFormBuilder(['id' => $id])
            ->add('id', \Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType::class)
            ->getForm()
        ;
    }
}
```

and

```
{% if delete_path is defined %}
    <form id="delete" action="{{ path(delete_path, {id: entity.id}) }}" method="POST" class="pull-right" style="margin-top: -43px; margin-right: 10px;">
        {{ form_widget(deleteForm) }}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">{{ delete_form_submit_button|trans }}</button>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

Please pay attention, that's not pseudo-code, is real code I've found into an application a friend of mine asked me to fix.

My question is ... why CSRF token isn't showed in the view?
As a result my form submission are always invalid due to csrf token missing

#### More details

- Symfony version: 2.8
- Even if I use `form_rest` token still not be there so it's seems like is not generated at all but, under the hood, it should have been there (`isValid()`)

#### EDIT

- If I dump `deleteForm`, `_token` is there but if I try to use `form_widget` or `form_row` or `form_rest` it is not showed
- If I don't use `form_widget(deleteForm)` or `form_row(deleteForm.id)`, the token in showed.

Comment: How about `{{ form_widget(deleteForm._token) }}` ?

Comment: @PawełMikołajczuk: not, that's will not produce anything

Comment: Is the `csrf.protection` set in `config.yml` and the csrf token correctly rendered on other forms ? It's really strange that `form_widget(deleteForm._token)` or `form_row(deleteForm._token)` doesn't produce anything, I try your code on a 2.8 project and it works well. Can you give more code of your template ? Maybe the form handling too.

Comment: @chalasr yes, other forms works as expected. I will provide more code tonight or tomorrow, but I'm quite experienced in symfony and I'm not doign anything strange or "hackish"

Comment: @DonCallisto I don't have any doubt about this. Something broke the token rendering, I'm thinking about an other form (or another element) that conflicts with the delete form. Maybe try to use it out of the current template (without any other markup).

Comment: @chalasr yes, is the first thing I've thought. BTW i'll give it a try, but that sounds very weird

Comment: You have to create or add token inside form. Here is a [link for token](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136188/symfony-2-add-csrf-token-when-using-a-form-without-a-class)

Comment: @BhavinNakrani: no, that's not the solution ...

Comment: @chalasr: I've dumped the form, CSRF is there. It's a very strange kind of issue. PS.: If i us `form_widget(deleteForm._token)` it is showed :\

Comment: @DonCallisto As we have a large number of CSRF issues, your problem sounds strange from the beginning... With your code as only element of the template, I have the token correctly rendered. Adding a `form_rest` or anything else make no difference from my side. I can't reproduce your bug

Comment: If I'm not mistaken form_widget also dumps <form> tags. So, are you nesting <form> tags and could that be causing your problems?

Comment: @putr you are not mistaken but this is not the problem. Already tried without and with single form_row

Comment: Remember that Symfony forms use a set of templates for the widgets. This file can be extended or overwritten to produce the results you are getting. Information can be found at: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html